# return by value inline functions

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, inline

I'm implementing some math types and I want to optimize the operators to minimize the amount of memory created, destroyed, and copied. To demonstrate I'll show you part of my Quaternion implementation.

```
class Quaternion
{
public:
    double w,x,y,z;

    ...

    Quaternion  operator+(const Quaternion &other) const;
}
```

I want to know how the two following implementations differ from eachother. I do have a += implementation that operates in-place to where no memory is created, but some higher level operations utilizing quaternions it's useful to use + and not +=.

```
__forceinline Quaternion Quaternion::operator+( const Quaternion &other ) const
{
    return Quaternion(w+other.w,x+other.x,y+other.y,z+other.z);
}
```

and

```
__forceinline Quaternion Quaternion::operator+( const Quaternion &other ) const
{
    Quaternion q(w+other.w,x+other.x,y+other.y,z+other.z);
    return q;
}
```

My c++ is completely self-taught so when it comes to some optimizations, I'm unsure what to do because I do not know exactly how the compiler handles these things. Also how do these mechanics translate to non-inline implementations.

Any other criticisms of my code are welcomed.

Comment: I don't know where __forceinline comes from, but it certainly isn't standard C++

Comment: it's compiler specific. It just forces the compiler to make it inline.

Comment: There's nothing we can say about this without knowing what your compiler is, since this is all compiler-dependent.

Comment: whatever visual studio uses. __forceinline is the same as inline, but inline in visual studio is a suggestion.

Comment: So what makes you (a self-confessed self-taught C++ programmer) think you know how to optimise better than the compiler does?

Comment: I'm trying to get the compiler to optimize better =] I'm just saying I don't know exactly what the compiler does so I'm wanting to make sure I'm not making it do the wrong thing. And as far as using __forceinline, I've seen it in other code before used simply to ensure that the code that is used the most is what gets optimized. I don't know what conditions the compiler chooses to not make something inline, but I'm doing it to be safe.

Comment: @Neil: Where do you see him claiming he can optimize better than the compiler?  He's made a statement that he wishes to limit memory management, which is a constraint the compiler could not be aware of.  Is that what you mean? My read is that he's trying to understand which programming choice will lead to the best code, given the memory constraint he specifies.

Comment: Little rule of thumb, unless you write wildly successful compilers or wrote the compiler you are using, you are not smarter than the compiler.  Are you aware of the assembly instruction difference between that function being inline or not in your program?  If the answer is no, then don't inline it.

Comment: In order for your optimization to limit memory, the inline instructions for your operator must take up less room than the call/jmp instructions. This is highly compiler/processor dependent but since you said you're using visual studio I have to assume this is not the case.  This also depends on the number of times you call the operator and where in your code you call it. These are all factors your compiler will take into account to make the best decision.

Comment: I'm aware of the idea behind inline functions, and I'm not concerned that an inline version would take up more memory than a non-inline version. I was asking about the memory optimization in respect to how I return the variables. Sorry if that wasn't clear, but I'm not making it inline so that it uses less memory.

Comment: Bear in mind that "inline", in C++, is a no-op.  It means nothing.  (In C, you can't take the address of an inline function, but this is not the case in C++.)  At best, it's a compiler hint, but any reasonable modern compiler is much better than you are at figuring out what should be inlined or not.

Comment: You're not quite right. At least the Visual C++ compiler will not allow you to get the address of an inline function. But you are correct in that it is a hint, and it will not necessarily use inline expansion. And I could be wrong, but it's my understanding that inline functions will almost always be faster as they require less instructions, but they require more memory because the instructions are not at a static point in memory. For my usage of these functions, I want them to use inline expansion.

Comment: Besides the compiler being smarter than the regular programmer (surely smarter than me at the very least), and leaving the 'inline' aside, I think this is quite a valid question: the programmer affects what the compiler can or cannot optimize. If you make an explicit call to a copy constructor the compiler is not allowed to elide that copy. No matter how smart the compiler is, according to the compiler, the sentence must be executed. This differs from argument passing or return values, where the user is not explictly requesting the copy.

Comment: The morale of the story is that even if you are not smarter than the compiler, certain idioms will help it optimize (if it deems so) or will force it into not optimizing. Passing by value is a clear example where you can help the compiler by providing extra information to the caller of the function: 'I will make a copy of the argument' instead of 'Give me a constant reference to the argument so that I can play with it in an unknown (to the compiler) way'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first example allows the compiler to potentially use somehting called "Return Value Optimization" (RVO).

The second example allows the compiler to potentially use something called "Named Return Value Optimization" (NRVO).  These 2 optimizations are clearly closely related.

Some details of Microsoft's implementation of NRVO can be found here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057.aspx

Note that the article indicates that NRVO support started with VS 2005 (MSVC 8.0). It doesn't specifically say whether the same applies to RVO or not, but I believe that MSVC used RVO optimizations before version 8.0.

[This article about Move Constructors by Andrei Alexandrescu](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403855) has good information about how RVO works (and when and why compilers might not use it).

Including this bit:

> you'll be disappointed to hear that each compiler, and often each compiler version, has its own rules for detecting and applying RVO. Some apply RVO only to functions returning unnamed temporaries (the simplest form of RVO). The more sophisticated ones also apply RVO when there's a named result that the function returns (the so-called Named RVO, or NRVO).
>
> In essence, when writing code, you can count on RVO being portably applied to your code depending on how you exactly write the code (under a very fluid definition of "exactly"), the phase of the moon, and the size of your shoes.

The article was written in 2003 and compilers should be much improved by now; hopefully, the phase of the moon is less important to when the compiler might use RVO/NRVO (maybe it's down to day-of-the-week). As noted above it appears that MS didn't implement NRVO until 2005. Maybe that's when someone working on the compiler at Microsoft got a new pair of more comfortable shoes a half-size larger than before.

Your examples are simple enough that I'd expect both to generate equivalent code with more recent compiler versions.

Comment: With current compilers, both snippets have about the same chances of having the optimization in place. Nowadays, what is really hard for compilers if applying RVO when the code has more than one return statement (that is, with different objects) as in that case, it is harder for the compiler to determine which of the different instances should be constructed over the return memory space.

Comment: There are also some other small changes that can help the compiler optimize and will never incur extra cost as using free function versions of the operator+ that take the first argument by value. In this case, the compiler can elide the construction / copy construction if the function is called with a temporary.

Answer (score 6):

Between the two implementations you presented, there really is no difference. Any compiler doing any sort of optimizations whatsoever will optimize your local variable out.

As for the += operator, a slightly more involved discussion about whether or not you want your Quaternions to be immutable objects is probably required... I would always lead towards creating objects like this as immutable objects. (but then again, I'm more of a managed coder as well)

Comment: And I'd always lean to making them mutable, on the basis that in C++, user-defined numeric types should (as far as possible) mimic int. In e.g. Java it's a different story, all your variables are references and immutable types are more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If these two implementations do not generate exactly the same assembly code when optimization is turned on, you should consider using a different compiler. :) And I don't think it matters whether or not the function is inlined.

By the way, be aware that `__forceinline` is very non-portable.  I would just use plain old standard `inline` and let the compiler decide.

Comment: Well atm I don't have to worry about portability because I'm the only one dealing with this code. I should probably use a macro though instead, but I'm not too worried about that right now.

Comment: First, writing portable code whenever possible is generally a good habit to have.  Second, even if nobody else ever looks at your code, you may want to use it on a different platform or with a different compiler someday.  Forcing a function to be inlined, when most compilers do a pretty good job of it on their own doesn't seem like a good reason to use a non-standard feature.  Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: I completely agree with your two cents, I was just too lazy to do that there. I'll change it now if it makes you happy =]

Comment: @Dima:  There's also the fact that you may want to look at your code several years in the future, when you aren't using the same compiler and don't quite remember what all the compiler-dependent things are.

Comment: the new and different compiler will surely help you remember ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The current consensus is that you should implement first all your ?= operators that do not create new objects. Depending on whether exception safety is a problem (in your case it probably is not) or a goal the definition of ?= operator can be different. After that you implement operator? as a free function in terms of the ?= operator using [pass-by-value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) semantics.

```
// thread safety is not a problem
class Q
{
   double w,x,y,z;
public:
   // constructors, other operators, other methods... omitted
   Q& operator+=( Q const & rhs ) {
      w += rhs.w;
      x += rhs.x;
      y += rhs.y;
      z += rhs.z;
      return *this;
   }
};
Q operator+( Q lhs, Q const & rhs ) {
   lhs += rhs;
   return lhs;
}
```

This has the following advantages:

- Only one implementation of the logic. If the class changes you only need to reimplement operator?= and operator? will adapt automatically.
- The free function operator is symmetric with respect to implicit compiler conversions
- It is the most efficient implementation of operator? you can find with respect to copies

**Efficiency of operator?**

When you call operator? on two elements, a third object must be created and returned. Using the approach above, the copy is performed in the method call. As it is, the compiler is able to elide the copy when you are passing a temporary object. Note that this should be read as 'the compiler *knows* that it can elide the copy', not as 'the compiler *will* elide the copy'. Mileage will vary with different compilers, and even the same compiler can yield different results in different compilation runs (due to different parameters or resources available to the optimizer).

In the following code, a temporary will be created with the sum of `a` and `b`, and that temporary must be passed again to `operator+` together with `c` to create a second temporary with the final result:

```
Q a, b, c;
// initialize values
Q d = a + b + c;
```

If `operator+` has pass by value semantics, the compiler can elide the pass-by-value copy (the compiler knows that the temporary will get destructed right after the second `operator+` call, and does not need to create a different copy to pass in)

Even if the `operator?` could be implemented as a one line function (`Q operator+( Q lhs, Q const & rhs ) { return lhs+=rhs; }`) in the code, it should not be so. The reason is that the compiler cannot know whether the reference returned by `operator?=` is in fact a reference to the same object or not. By making the return statement explicitly take the `lhs` object, the compiler knows that the return copy can be elided.

**Symmetry with respect to types**

If there is an implicit conversion from type `T` to type `Q`, and you have two instances `t` and `q` respectively of each type, then you expect `(t+q)` and `(q+t)` both to be callable. If you implement `operator+` as a member function inside `Q`, then the compiler will not be able to convert the `t` object into a temporary `Q` object and later call `(Q(t)+q)` as it cannot perform type conversions in the left hand side to call a member function. Thus with a member function implementation `t+q` will not compile.

Note that this is also true for operators that are not symmetric in arithmetic terms, we are talking about types. If you can substract a `T` from a `Q` by promoting the `T` to a `Q`, then there is no reason not to be able to substract a `Q` from a `T` with another automatic promotion.